# Prescription of mapping f: N x N → N which is not injection and surjection

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Does exists prescription of mapping f: N x N → N which is not injection and surjection?

Could you please help me with that? Thank you

Comment: $f((n, t)) = c$ for fixed $c \in \mathbb{N} $ is neither injective nor surjective. There are infinitely many other examples.

Comment: What is a prescription of mapping?! The map f(a,b)=a+1 is neither injective nor surjective. f(1,1)=f(1,2), so f is not injective. 0 is not in the image of f, so f is not surjective.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be any constant map. For example $f:\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ by $f((n, m))= k$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ fixed.